# Determine the set of points at which the function $F(x, y) = \frac{xy}{ 1+e^{x-y}}$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Determine the set of points at which the function is continuous.

$$F(x, y) = \frac{xy}{ 1+e^{x-y}}$$

I get that the function is continuous when $e^{x-y} \neq -1$ and I'm supposed to write the intervals that satisfy the equation, but I don't know how to do that when there is two variables instead of one. also I don't know how to determine the set of all x and y that makes $e^{x-y} = -1$. 
I looked online for solutions, none. my book is kind of confusing me. its too late to ask my teacher. help plz.

Comment: Hint: assuming $x$ and $y$ are real, what properties of the exponential formula do you know?

Comment: Isn't e^(x-y) >= 0 for all x and y? How could it be =-1?

Comment: i am forgetting everything today... need sleep

Comment: i guess the set of points would then be (-infinity, infinity)

Comment: You have two variables, so the set of points will be the plane, not the line.